# Create MySQL database with sql file import in a single line

Tags: mysql

I have a sql file that I want to upload from the command line. To do this I first need to go into MySQL and create the database

```
mysql> create database myDB;
```

and then call the following from the command line:

```
mysql -u username -p myDB < myDB.sql
```

Is there a way to do this all in one line from the command line?

I tried adding the following lines (and various combinations) to the beginning of the `myDB.sql` file:

```
create database `myDB`;
use `myDB`;
```

and then running

```
mysql -u username -p < myDB.sql
```

but that did not work.

```
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 7: No database selected
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.sql` files are generally LITERALLY just a sequence of SQL DDL/DML queries. If it was created by mysqldump, then it should contain EVERYTHING needed to recreate the database from the ground up, including the necessary `create db` and `create table` queries.

if they're not there, you can manually add them to the top of the file yourself via simple file concatenation/modification, e.g.

```
echo 'create database foo;' > new.sql
cat otherstuff.sql >> new.sql
mysql < new.sql
```

Comment: Like I said in my question, I've tried that and it did not work. The top of the sql file LITERALLY says `create database myDB; use myDB;`

Comment: dose the account you're using to log into mysql have the permissions to do that? you'd definitely need to be granted the `create` permission.

Comment: I'm running as root. I can definitely manually log into mysql as root and create the tables.

Comment: well, I tried a basic create db/create table/insert thing, and if the db OR table already exists, then the rest of the script is ignored. check if the db already exists? or do `create database if not exists` instead, similarly for the tables.

Comment: That weirdly worked, no idea why it needed the if not exists. Thanks!

Comment: so yeah. the `create` call (either of them) would fail if the table/db already existed, and that would abort the rest of the script. You may want to instead add a `drop` command first, especially if you're not 100% sure that the table structure WON'T change between dump/reload time. otherwise you may be inserting into a table whose structure is different. no biggie if you added fields, but if you removed/changed fields, you can end up with garbage in the db at best.

Comment: The weird thing is that the database absolutely didn't exist so no idea why it was failing. Oh well. Thanks again.

Comment: `cat 'create database foo;' > new.sql` returns `cat: create database foo;: No such file or directory`
i believe it should be `echo 'create database foo;' > new.sql`

Answer (score 5):

If you generated the mysqldump file with the `--databases` or `--all-databases` options, then it puts the correct CREATE DATABASE statements into the dump file.

Answer (score 0):

*MySQL* reference article [Copying MySQL Databases to Another Machine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/copying-databases.html) suggests a two-commands solution to this question, creating a database with the *MySQL* server administration program [mysqladmin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqladmin.html).

```bash
mysqladmin -u username -p create myDB
mysql -u username -p myDB < myDB.sql
```